# How to make the text in a button change color when I hover over it using CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using the OceanWP WordPress theme and on the top-bar menu I have created a button called "Post a Job" using CSS.

https://prnt.sc/y5s2v9

I am using two top-bar menus, one which shows when users are logged in and one which is shown when users are logged out.

The "post a job" button has a 2px purple border and purple background. The purple colour is #43455C and the text is white.
But when you hover over it, I wanted the background to change to the same colour as the top bar, #5cd895, and the text to change purple: #43455C so I used the code:

```
/* Post a Job Button on logged-in top bar menu */
body #menu-item-840 a{
    color:#fff;
}
#menu-item-840 a{
    font-weight: 600;
    border: 2px solid #43455C;
    background-color: #43455C;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 2px 20px
    }
#menu-item-1272 a:hover {
    color: #43455C;
    background-color: #5cd895;
}

/* Post a Job Button on logged-out top bar menu */
body #menu-item-1272 a{
    color:#fff;
}
#menu-item-1272 a{
    font-weight: 600;
    border: 2px solid #43455C;
    background-color: #43455C;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 2px 20px
    }
#menu-item-1272 a:hover {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

But when the user is logged in and hovers over the "post a job" button when they are logged in, the text just changes to the default "black" colour and the background does not change:

https://prnt.sc/y5soqq

and when the user is logged out and I hover over the "post a job" button the background changes white and the text turns to the default black: https://prnt.sc/y5sqo8

I have adjusted the CSS several times but for some reason, it just defaults to these colours when you hover over it.

Could anybody advise what is wrong with the CSS code?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error in your CSS.

When the user is logged, your CSS hover code is on the item #menu-item-1272 and not on the #menu-item-840.

```
body #menu-item-840 a{
    color:#fff;
}
#menu-item-840 a{
    font-weight: 600;
    border: 2px solid #43455C;
    background-color: #43455C;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 2px 20px
    }
#menu-item-840 a:hover { /* Error Here, i've replaced 1272 by 840. */
    color: #43455C;
    background-color: #5cd895;
}

/* Post a Job Button on logged-out top bar menu */
body #menu-item-1272 a{
    color:#fff;
}
#menu-item-1272 a{
    font-weight: 600;
    border: 2px solid #43455C;
    background-color: #43455C;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 2px 20px
    }
#menu-item-1272 a:hover {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. I have changed the menu item 1272 to 840, when user is logged in and also I realised that the background-color for the item when user is logged out is #fff which I changed to #5cd895. It is now working but still when I hover over the button the text text is still black, even when I change the `color: #000` to #43455C. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Is your text inside the ```<a> </a>``` ? I think i can't find the problem without seing the html code of the button.

Comment: I'm not sure it is just added to the top-bar via the appearence>menus option from the dashboard: https://prnt.sc/y5vycz 
Does this help at all?

Comment: I don't know how wordpress add it. WP probably override the color of the text. Can you check with the browser's development tool  ?

Comment: I checked using inspect and I don't think it is inside <a> </a>. Here is item 840: https://prnt.sc/y5xcqg
 Is this what you meant?

Comment: What's inside the <li> ?